# It's possible to use a transparency map in an OBJ within three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, wavefront

I am trying to add a transparency map to an OBJ imported to my three.js scene but it is not working (it shows the model and the other materials but without the transparency map). I already played with the D value. Is it even possible to achieve what I want?

This is the JS code used to import the materials and the OBJ:

```
new THREE.MTLLoader()
                    .setPath( 'assets/models/' )
                    .setMaterialOptions({side: THREE.DoubleSide})
                    .load( '10_negro2.mtl', function ( materials ) {
                        materials.preload();
                        new THREE.OBJLoader()
                            .setMaterials( materials )
                            .setPath( 'assets/models/' )
                            .load( '10_negro2.obj', function ( object ) {
                                object.position.y = -30;
                                object.name = "vestido1";
                                scene.add( object );
                            }, onProgress, onError );
                    } );
```

And this are the material values:

```
newmtl lambert3SG
illum 4
Kd 0.80 0.80 0.80
Ka 0.00 0.00 0.00
Tf 1.00 1.00 1.00
Ks 0 0 0
d 0.500
map_d 10_Negro_Encaje_con_Flores_1920_ALPHA.jpg
map_Kd 10_Negro_Encaje_con_Flores_1920_TXT.jpg
bump 10_Negro_Encaje_con_Flores_1920_NM.jpg -bm 1
Ni 1.00
```

[image]

Hope someone can explain me about this a little bit. I'm new to this. Thanks.

Comment: It does not appear `MTLLoader` supports an alpha map, but you should be able to modify `MTLLoader.js`  and add `case 'map_d'`.

Comment: Thanks WestLangley, will read the documentation about that. :)

Comment: Give this a try: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/14822